# PHP Why $argv type data is always return a string

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I want to know why `$argv[1]` is always a string?.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D21WM.png)

Comment: Because __every agrument__ passed to command line has type __string__.

Comment: ouhhh.. Then how to input an integer or even float from command line? Plz help

Comment: Cast value to integer in your script.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the code as code and not a image. To learn more on how to ask on Stack Overflow, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask